# In Firefox and IE how can change the cursor while dragging over different targets?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

Doing drag and drop in HTML5, I need to be able to change the cursor depending upon the drop target.  In Chrome this works by changing the dropEffect,

```
 if (e.currentTarget.id == 'dropMove') {
     e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
 } else {
     e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'link';
 }
```

however changing the dropEffect in IE and Firefox has no effect on the cursor.  See the following Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ksoncan34/s7kN5/

I've tried manually setting the cursor, with window.cursor, but this also has no effect.  How can I change the cursor for different drop targets in Firefox and IE?

Comment: Which operating system and browser versions are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 and 8.1, browsers are the latest Firefox (29.0.1) and IE 11.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu with latest Firefox, its working fine for both cursor.

Comment: It looks to me, that the effect must be set in dragStart and cannot be changed in dragover etc. Something in a sense, that the dragged item declares in what way its meant to be dragged and targets have no say in this.

Comment: Working fine in Firefox 29.0.1 and 25.0 on OS X 10.9.3. Sounds like this might be a Windows-only bug.

Comment: Works on Xubuntu 14.04 with FF 29.0 and on Chromium (if this is of any relevance for you) it seems like the cursor changes only on the _drop move_ field not on the _drop link_ field.

Comment: Has anyone besides the OP reproduced this issue? It works fine in Firefox on my machine.

Comment: @sphanley I can confirm the OP's behavior on Win7SP1 w/ FF29.0.1.

Comment: I reproduced the issue with IE11 and FF (Win7 x64). It works with Chrome. I tried to fix that yesterday... That is crazy, I don't get what is the "moveLink" effectAllowed for. If you finally can only have one effect! This is non sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using jQuery ui -- droppable and draggable.

You can hide the default/actual cursor using `cursor: none` and use a stylized DOM element to render your own 'cursor' element.

I've provided an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/lawrencealan/WMyu7/78/ *(updated 6/8/2017)*

Note: `mousemove` stops firing during dragging of "draggable" attributed elements.

--

EDIT: As of September 2019, the example is now broken.

Comment: Wish that the example wasn't built with jQueryUI as I don't want to have to build in that dependency, but turning the cursor off and creating a pseudo cursor is the best solution I have seen so far.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can always use a customized jqueryui build that only has the `draggable` and `droppable` functionality, or implement that functionality on your own. Just have to keep track of the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events... not to mention touch. I wasn't about to do that for the example... maybe when I'm bored one day ;) -- check out http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/simple-dragdrop-with-javascript-jquery/

Comment: suggesting to use something else is not a valid answer in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the support for cursor change on `.dropeffect` seems to be lacking.

You could try to attach an element to the mouse X and Y coords and manipulate that as it moves, but it can get messy. I think that [lawrencealan's jQuery UI solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24167550/2126792), which does just that, is probably the only reliable way to do this... and is actually quite simple. Still I would like to suggest an alternative which may suit your needs just as well, and does not require jQuery UI:

**Alternative:**

Instead of binding code to mousemove and dealing with unreliable cursor manipulations, I would suggest to simply have the targets change their appearance when you drag over them.

For example: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7kN5/60/)**

Add something like this to your dragover function:

```
$(this).addClass('draggedover');
```

Make sure to remove it on dragleave:

```
$('.drop').bind('dragleave', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass('draggedover');
});
```

And then add some CSS to go along with it:

```
.draggedover::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/czlkT.jpg');
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#dropMove.draggedover::before {
    background-position: -110px -70px;
}

#dropLive.draggedover::before {
    background-position: -5px -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link while searching:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780585/dropeffect-not-working-properly-in-ie-standard-mode-ie9-ie10

Looks like Microsoft is rejecting this as working by design. What might help is the 3rd comment that suggest a way to fix the usability issue. He did not share any code though.